# Using GNU screen to run commands consecutively (next one runs only after previous one finishes)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, gnu-screen

I'm trying to use a screen command to stack multiple commands one after another. First I run a python script and then I connect to an ssh host like this.

$HOSTNAME is slave-node-1
$arg is arg2

```
screen -dmS 1 sh -c "python3 pyscript1.py arg && \
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key user@remote-node \
"sed -i '/$HOSTNAME-pyscript1-$arg/s/$/1/' ~/test.txt"\
;exec bash"
```

The reason I am using screen is because this isn't the only command I need to run and I need to be able to monitor the output of pyscript1.py as it runs.

The command is supposed to create new screen named "1", run the script pyscript1.py with the arg "arg", **and only when that command finishes**, I want to connect to the remote-host using that command to make a change in a file.

exec bash is meant to keep the screen open even after the commands finish.

The sed command works when I type it separately.

I am also able to create a screen named "1" using `screen -dmS 1`.

I am also able to connect to the server using SSH.

However, when I run the above command, nothing happens. A new screen isn't even created.

when i run

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key user@remote-node "sed -i '/$HOSTNAME-pyscript1-$arg/s/$ 1/' test.txt"
```

I get the desired effect

but when i try

```
screen -dmS 1 sh -c "ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key user@remote-node "sed -i '/$HOSTNAME-pyscript1-$arg/s/$ 1/' test.txt";exec bash"
```

nothing happens

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is unclear to me on which system `$HOSTNAME` is to be expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several quoting problems.

Original:

```
screen -dmS 1 sh -c "python3 pyscript1.py arg && ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key user@remote-node "sed -i '/$HOSTNAME-pyscript1-$arg/s/$/1/ ~/test.txt;exec bash"
```

readable version with line breaks

```
screen -dmS 1 sh -c "python3 pyscript1.py arg && ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key "\
"user@remote-node "sed -i '/$HOSTNAME-pyscript1-$arg/s/$/1/ ~/test.txt;exec bash"
```

I guess that

```
"sed -i '/$HOSTNAME-pyscript1-$arg/s/$/1/ ~/test.txt"
```

is supposed to be the argument for `ssh`.

Corrected code:

```
screen -dmS 1 sh -c "python3 pyscript1.py arg && ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key "\
"user@remote-node \"sed -i '/$HOSTNAME-pyscript1-$arg/s/$/1/' ~/test.txt\";"\
"exec bash"
```

Comment: exec bash is separate, it's meant to keep the screen open. sorry I forgot to put the quotation marks, please have another look at the question.

Comment: when i run ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key user@remote-node "sed -i '/$HOSTNAME-pyscript1-$arg/s/$ 1/' test.txt" the correct thing happens

Comment: but when i try screen -dmS 1 sh -c "ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key user@remote-node "sed -i '/$HOSTNAME-pyscript1-$arg/s/$ 1/' test.txt";exec bash" nothing happens

Comment: @anarchy Of course. You are not supposed to use your code any more but mine instead.

Comment: i just realised your backslashes were used for escape, my bad, I thought they were meant to show new lines, anyway now i get -bash "exec bash: command not found

Comment: i understand what you are trying to do i figured out the right answer, I just needed to escape the two quotation marks for the sed command